# Calculating the average error margin of a non-linear approximation?

Tags: integration

I have a formula that I'm using to approximate a function in a manner very similar to linear approximation, except my method isn't linear.  The formula I'm using is piecewise, but it appears to be continuous to me.  When I look up margin of error I get a lot of statistics stuff about probability and expected result vs actual result, but I don't think that really applies to my problem.

I made a graph of the error margin, and my intuition is to use integration to find the area underneath the curve (I used absolute value for my error margin, so the underestimates and overestimates count equally and don't cancel out).  I'm not really sure where to go from here.  Maybe divide the number I get from integration by the range of the domain?  My estimation is only good for numbers from about 1 to 1150, so I would divide the "total error" by 1149?

Basically, is this an accurate way to calculate the average error, and if not, what would be?

Edit: Apparently this is called "calculating the average value of a function over an interval" so I can probably figure this out myself now that I have a name for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: is your function a secret?

Comment: No, but I haven't really figured out how to format equations just yet, and I'm still working on the formula.  It's extremely similar to linear approximation, and not really any more complicated.  I have it figured out in English pretty well but I'm still working on defining it in precise, mathematical terms.